# Swipeleft or Swiperight not changing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I have this issue with trying to make a page change upon a swipe on a Appery.io app.  The swipe gesture is working but the page is not changing, and using `$(this).next('[data-role="page"]` always gives me a length of 0.

Here is the make up of the page:

[image]

Here is how the console looks with the `$(this).next('[data-role="page"]`:

[image]

This is the code I am currently testing:

```
$('.ui-mobile').on("swipeleft",'[data-role="page"]', function () {
    console.log('swipe next page');
    var next = $(this).next('[data-role="page"]');
    console.log(next);
    if (next.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(next, "slide", false, true);
    }
});
```

So to recap.  The swipe works, as the console logs it. When I look at the 'nextsibling' is aways shows home, and the same for 'previoussibling'  I am not sure thats the correct attribute to look at either.

I have looked around and seen a few posts similar, each with ticks, but not matter which I look at and test, its the same result. The length is always 0.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Addy

Comment: I disagree this is a duplicate, in mobile jQuery 1.5 when released 'activePage' will be removed.  So using your solution is only temporary ?  Please change your view.

Comment: @Omar, please remove the duplicate tag.  This is not a duplicate and your answer does NOT resolve my problem!  I have waited an hour and ignoring me will not work.

Comment: You didn't mention which version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Bind swipe events to document, and then check whether active page has a page before `.prev()` or `.after()` it.

```
$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {
    if (event.type == 'swipeleft') {
        var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"),
            nextPage = activePage.next('[data-role=page]');
        if (nextPage) {
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", nextPage, {
                transition: "flip"
            });
        }
    }
    if (event.type == 'swiperight') {
        var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"),
            prevPage = activePage.prev('[data-role=page]');
        if (prevPage) {
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", prevPage, {
                transition: "flip",
                reverse: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bd62e15f/)**

Comment: This did not work.  I am using Appery.io with a template.  Changing the document is not what I want changing, but the active div.  Maybe I am trying the wrong way to do this.  But I should add the classes to make it active.  The swipe worked, but so did mine, but the page in your example is showing a empty page, with on template or anything ?

Comment: @AndrewWalker In the code above, it changes pages div not document. You want to changes pages (HTML) or pages (divs)?

Comment: I was trying to change the document, because it looks as though, even with a template, the whole page loads new, even though its a template. So it looks like the template reloads with the new active div (or page).  But by reloading the document and not the div, you get the same page. and nothing changes.  In your example the document changes to a blank page.

Comment: @AndrewWalker so you're trying to load a fresh HTML page right?

Comment: I think that is what its trying to do.  I need to look into this further.  To me it looks like it needs to reload the whole page and add a new div, which contents from another file

Comment: @AndrewWalker in this case, you need to decide whether you want to load next/prev pages via Ajax. If Ajax is disabled, `$.mobile.pageContainer.....("change")` isn't what you need, `window.location.href="file.html"` is the function you need. Also, you should add a custom attribute to page div that holds value of next/prev page, e.g. `data-next="foo.html"` and `data-prev="bar.html"`.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you.  Thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59010/discussion-between-omar-and-andrew-walker).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Omar I have managed to resolve this.

Because `changePage` and `activePage` are

> deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0.

I needed a version that would last, so I have managed to fix it using the following code:

```
$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {

    //Check current page id
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    //Get div (page) id
    activePage = activePage.attr('id');
    //Get number of page ie page1, page2, page3 page4 etc
    var activePageNo = activePage.slice(4);
    //Get current full URL
    var activeURL = $(location).attr('href');
    //Remove div (page) ref from url
    activeURL = activeURL.substr(0,activeURL.indexOf("#"));


    //Set up new numbers for next and prev swipes
    var np = parseInt(activePageNo)+1;
    var pp = parseInt(activePageNo)-1;
    //Set full div (page) ids 
    var prevPage = '';
    var nextPage =  'page' + np;
    if(activePageNo > 0) {
        prevPage = 'page' + pp;
    } else {
        prevPage = 'page0';
    }

    if (event.type == 'swipeleft') {
       if (nextPage) {
           $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", activeURL + '#' + nextPage, {
               transition: "slide"
           });
       }
    }

    if (event.type == 'swiperight') {
        if (prevPage) {
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", activeURL + '#' + prevPage, {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps others looking to change from the old 1.4 and be ready for the new 1.5 :)